# GetClaimsAsync vs GenerateUserIdentityAsync for adding custom claims

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, httpcontext

I am wanting to add a custom claim to the user identity when they login so it gets included in as a claim in the auth cookie which is generated, and will redirect the user if the claim is present after logging in.

I don't want this claim to end up in the AspNetUserClaims table however.

I am currently using GetClaimsAsync to get the base claims first and then just adding the custom one on. However, when I try call Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.User at the end of the login action, that custom claim is not there. Should I be using GenerateUserIdentityAsync instead?

Thanks

Comment: MVC5 or Asp.Net Core?

Comment: @trailmax Using MVC5

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the same issue as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45457309/809357)?

Also if you are adding a custom claim, better add it in `ApplicationUser.GenerateUserIdentityAsync` method. You can add claims elsewhere, but this will be overwritten next time `SecurityStampValidator` is regenerating the cookie.